# How do I take a string and split it into 2 variables in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a string that is read in from a file in the format "firstname lastname". I want to split that string and put it into two separate variables `$first` and `$last`. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

read can do the splitting itself, e.g.

```
read  first last < name.txt

echo "$first"
echo "$last"
```

Comment: Or if you have them in a variable already, `set - $variable; first=$1; last=$2`

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on fgm's answer, whenever you have a string containing tokens *separated by single characters which are not part of any of the tokens*, and *terminated by a newline character*, you can use the internal field separator (`IFS`) and `read` to split it. Some examples:

```
echo 'John Doe' > name.txt
IFS=' ' read first last < name.txt
echo "$first"
John
echo "$last"
Doe

echo '+12 (0)12-345-678' > number.txt
IFS=' -()' read -a numbers < number.txt
for num in "${numbers[@]}"
do
    echo $num
done
+12
0
12
345
678
```

A typical mistake is to think that `read < file` is equivalent to `cat file | read` or `echo contents | read`, but this is not the case: The read command in a pipe is run in a separate subshell, so the values are lost once `read` completes. To fix this, you can either do all the operations with the variables in the same subshell:

```
echo 'John Doe' | { read first last; echo $first; echo $last; }
John
Doe
```

or if the text is stored in a variable, you can redirect it:

```
name='John Doe'
read first last <<< "$name"
echo $first
John
echo $last
Doe
```

Answer (score 2):

**cut** can split strings into parts separated by a chosen character :

```
first=$(echo $str | cut -d " " -f 1)
last=$(echo $str | cut -d " " -f 2)
```

It is probably not the most elegant way but it is certainly simple.

Answer (score -1):

```
$first=`echo $line | sed -e 's/([^ ])+([^ ])+/\1/'`
$last=`echo $line | sed -e 's/([^ ])+([^ ])+/\2/'`
```

Comment: hmm... looks like I need to re-read my unix tools book, it indeed doesn't work, I just wrote what's in my memory. sorry...